# How not to display all the boxes when I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is a portion of a website I am building and I am finding it a little bit to solve this problem. I wanna make a kind of filter but my problem is that I don't want all the boxes to display first when I refresh the page or when the page is loaded. I dont want to display all the boxes, but instead boxes in their category.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css'>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./loader.css">


</head>

<body>
<!-- ======================================================================= -->
<!-- START DGIGITA -->
<!-- ======================================================================= -->
<section class="section" id="digital">
<div class="container">
<div class="digital-content">
<ul class="digital-filter">
<li class="active" data-value="brand">Recharger son compte</li>
<li data-value="design">Packet Data</li>
<li data-value="photos">Token PLN</li>
</ul>
<div class="digital-items">
<a href="#" class="item animated zoomIn brand">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/kPO2m5T.jpg">
<div class="item-data">
<h4 class="title">Project 1</h4>
<p class="subtitle">Brand</p>
</div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="item animated zoomIn design">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/z83W7Yl.jpg">
<div class="item-data">
<h4 class="title">Project 2</h4>
<p class="subtitle">Design</p>
</div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="item animated zoomIn photos">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/63nBCF4.jpg">
<div class="item-data">
<h4 class="title">Project 3</h4>
<p class="subtitle">Photos</p>
</div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="item animated zoomIn brand">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/n9hk6NY.jpg">
<div class="item-data">
<h4 class="title">Project 4</h4>
<p class="subtitle">Brand</p>
</div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="item animated zoomIn photos">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/RIa8TBi.jpg" >
<div class="item-data">
<h4 class="title">Project 5</h4>
<p class="subtitle">Photos</p>
</div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="item animated zoomIn design">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/kzx1nz9.jpg">
<div class="item-data">
<h4 class="title">Project 6</h4>
<p class="subtitle">Design</p>
</div>
</a>
<div class="clear-fix"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<!-- ======================================================================= -->
<!-- END DIGITAL -->
<!-- ======================================================================= -->

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

</body>

</html>


// Digital filter
$(function () {
'use strict';
$('#digital ul.digital-filter li').on('click', function () {
// var linkValue = $(this).attr()
$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
});

$(function () {
'use strict';
$('#digital ul.digital-filter li:first-of-type').on('click', function () {
$('#digital .digital-items .item').hide(0).fadeIn(0);
});
});


$(function () {
'use strict';
$('#digital ul.digital-filter li:not(:first-of-type)').on('click', function () {
$('#digital .digital-items .item').hide(0);
$('.' + $(this).data('value')).show(0);
});
});






*,
*:after,
*:before {
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.container {
margin: 0 auto;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.container {
width: 1170px;
}
}


.clear-fix,
.clear-fix:after,
.clear-fix:before {
content: '';
display: table;
clear: both;
}

.active a {
color: #007BFF;
}

ul,
li {
list-style: none;
}

li {
display: inline-block;
}

a,
a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
}


.rotate {
transform: rotate(90deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.section {
padding: 100px 0;
}

#digital .section-heading .section-subtitle {
margin: 30px 0;
}

#digital .digital-content .digital-filter li {
padding: 5px 10px;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 500;
}

#digital .digital-content .digital-filter li.active {
color: #007BFF;
}


#digital .digital-content .digital-items {
margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}

#digital .digital-content .digital-items .item {
position: relative;
display: block;
float: left;
width: calc(100% / 3 - 20px);
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
border: 3px solid #000000;
}

#digital .digital-content .digital-items .item:nth-child(1){
border: 3px solid #FF1A1A;
}

#digital .digital-content .digital-items .item:nth-child(2){
border: 3px solid #33CC00;
}

#digital .digital-content .digital-items .item:nth-child(3){
border: 3px solid #1A1AFF;
}

#digital .digital-content .digital-items .item:nth-child(4){
border: 3px solid #FF1A1A;
}

#digital .digital-content .digital-items .item:nth-child(5){
border: 3px solid #1A1AFF;
}

#digital .digital-content .digital-items .item:nth-child(6){
border: 3px solid #33CC00;
}
















#digital .digital-content .digital-items .item:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
display: block;
margin: auto;
left: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 90%;
height: 90%;
background-color: rgba(0, 123, 255, .7);
z-index: 1;
opacity: 0;
transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}


#digital .digital-content .digital-items .item-data {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 30%;
transform: translate(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%);
-o-transform: translate(-50%);
transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
z-index: 2;
opacity: 0;
}

#digital .digital-content .digital-items .item-data .title {
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 400;
color: #fff;
}


#digital .digital-content .digital-items .item-data .subtitle {
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 400;
color: #fff;
}


#digital .digital-content .digital-items .item:hover:before {
opacity: 1;
}
#digital .digital-content .digital-items .item:hover .item-data {
top: 50%;
opacity: 1;
}
#digital .digital-content .digital-items .item img {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function () {
'use strict';
  // Initial setup:
  // set the name of the starting category
  var startingCategory = "brand";
  // add the active class to the li item in the menu:
  $('#digital ul.digital-filter li[data-value="' + startingCategory + '"]').addClass('active');
  // hide everything apart from the startingCategory (using the :not() css selector):
  $('#digital .digital-items .item:not(.' + startingCategory + ')').hide();
  //
  $('#digital ul.digital-filter li').on('click', function () {
    // store the name of data-value
    var value = $(this).data("value");

    // add active to clicked li, remove from all others:
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    // Hide All boxes first
    $.when($('#digital .digital-items .item').fadeOut(0)).then(function () {
      // after all boxes are hidden show only the ones you want
      // uses $.when to check the animation has finished on all boxes
      $('#digital .digital-items .item' + '.' + value).show();
   });
  });
});
```

You can see it working on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wftrxe97/1/)

Another way you can just trigger the `click()` event on one of the menu items, but depending on the animation speed/delays will show all boxes at page load and then animate "away", whereas this way, it should hide the unneeded boxes swiftly.

Comment: Thanks dw for helping me, I appreciate